# can we invoke the processor during global state store restoration?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I read [Kafka streams use cases for add global store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029964/kafka-streams-use-cases-for-add-global-store?rq=1) 
this stackover flow discuss and come to know that global-state store skip processor during the restoration.

is there any way to force global state store not to skip processor.

because input topic doesn't have any key inside the processor we are constructing the key and put in state store.

i seen many solution to create a custom change log topic that will be use as a source topic for global state store.

but i want how i can force global state store to run processor during restoration with processor api.

Answer (score 0):

> This is currently not supported until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7663 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8037 are resolved.

Compare: [Kafka Streams Global Store - Adding change log topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439113/kafka-streams-global-store-adding-change-log-topic)